# how to Add Minutes in date time result as 24 Hours Format

Tags: c#, datetime

I have getting two value from date and time control and after that i use add minutes in that 
Example  - `datePickerReadyDate.Text` i have value `05/07/2014` and `TimePickerReadyTime.Text` have value is `10:05` And i am adding minutes in time.  i am getting  result `05/07/2014 02:05 PM` but i want the result as `05/07/2014 14:05` . Below is my code .

```
 int Time = 240;    
  DateTime _readyTime = Convert.ToDateTime(datePickerReadyDate.Text + " " + TimePickerReadyTime.Text);
  var dm = _readyTime.AddMinutes(Time);                         
  delDate = dm.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm");
```

How can i do this . Thanks in advance .

Comment: You are looking for "H" to replace your "hh". See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx for more information on the format strings. This doesn't really justify an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the code for getting 24h clock from `DateTime.ToString()` is `HH`.

```
delDate = dm.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HH instead of hh:

```
  delDate = dm.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm");
```

See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Write down HH instead of hh  as shown below :-

```
  delDate = dm.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm");
```

Answer (score 0):

hh--> The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 01 to 12.

HH--> The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 00 to 23.

```
delDate = dm.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm");
```

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)